# absolute max shear and moment

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

For the maximum moment occur under the 1.5k load , why when we consider the left part of the beam, we just need to consider the forces 2k and 1.5k only ?

How about FR = 4.5k and also the 1k ? 
Cant i just consider all of them ? That's means i make an iamginary cut after the 1k load ... 
[image: jj]

[image: njj]

Answer (score 2):

You can always find the bending moment at a given point by calculating the moment generated by all the forces to one side of the point. So, you can calculate it as $M = A_yD_A + 2D_2$ (left section) ***OR*** as $M = B_yD_B + 1D_1$ (right section), where the $D$'s are the lever arms, since both sections must give equal results.

In this case, the authors chose to calculate from the left section, but that was just their personal choice.

The resultant force of 4.5 kN is completely irrelevant for this and was only used to calculate the reactions $A_y$ and $B_y$.

Comment: Where is DB ? DA ? D2 ? Can you explain based on the case in the notes , i still didnt get what do you mean

Comment: They are the distance between the relevant force and the point where the 1.5kN is applied. So $D_A$ is the distance from the 1.5kN to A (16.67ft), $D_1$ is the distance from the 1.5kN to the 1kN (5ft) and $D_2$ is the distance from the 1.5kN to the 2kN (10ft).

Comment: why for the left section , we dont have to consider forces  4.5 kN and 1k ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks - The 4.5k isn't a separate force, it's the resultant/total force applied force. You could consider the 1k force, but by inspection it won't cause the maximum moment (it's the same distance from the beam centre as the 2k force, and smaller than the 2k force, hence the moment underneath it will be smaller).

Comment: @kelvinmacks, as AndyT stated, you don't include the 4.5kN force because, well, there is no 4.5kN force. It is just the result of the actual, real forces (2, 1 and 1.5kN). It doesn't actually exist and is therefore ignored for this calculation (it is only useful to calculate the support reactions, nothing more).

Comment: @kelvinmacks: And you ignore the 1kN because, when you're looking at the left section of the beam up to the 1.5kN, you can't see the 1kN (since it is to the right of the 1.5kN and we're only looking to the left of it). If you don't understand why this works, that's another question entirely and a very basic one at that, so I once again suggest you go back to the beginning of the book. You are having trouble with this basic stuff but are also asking about influence lines, which are a pretty advanced subject. I really think you need to nail down the basics before anything.

Comment: ok , i can understand all the last 3 posts , thank you . But , for why for the left section , we nned to consider up to the 1.5k force only ? Can we consider up to 1k force ( in this case , we have 2.5k , 2k , 1.5k and also 1k in the question of moment about S)

Comment: @kelvinmacks, if you consider everything up to the 1k force, you'll get the bending moment up to that point. That's how it works: whichever point you choose, if you consider everything up to that point, you'll have calculated the bending moment for that point.

Comment: @Wasabi , how do we choose the point that we want to calculate the moment actually ? Since the question ask for the max moment occur unde the 1.5 k load , so we need to consider the moment about S up to 1.5 k load only ?